# Data binding controls in C# code (.cs file)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have been searching for data binding but instead of being in xaml i am searching for being in .cs file, is there a manner (property) that allows me to bind the specific property to a variable?

I want to bind the "Text" property of the "Entry" control but the problem is that how do i do it?

this is what i have tried, but i'm not sure about it beacuse OBVIOUSLY the code wasn't correct

```
textBox.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, 
      "MainViewModel.GetInstance().SubtasksList[TaskNumber - 1]");
```

code:

```
var textBox = new Entry()
{
           Placeholder = "ex Math homework",
   TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#18E1BF"),
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   Text = MainViewModel.GetInstance().SubtasksList[TaskNumber - 1]
};

textBox.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, 
      "MainViewModel.GetInstance().SubtasksList[TaskNumber - 1]");
```

when i want to take the data from the property (list index) just it didnt get changed, so why?

In other words, what I want to do is this:

```
<Entry
               Text="{Binding EntryText}”
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="Large"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

But instead of XAML file, use .cs file
How I do it?

Comment: what do .GetInstance()? I think SubtasksList is not bindable property.

Comment: GetInstance() is part of my single ton patron so by it I access to a same instance and access a list that will contain every entry text by a property I have created of integer type that allows me to index the list in fact of replace every value that it’s in the list for the text that is on every entry, my problems resides when I want to see the values of the list, in other words, the entries that the user “enter”, but when I check it still appears all the element of the list as empty string,hope you understand please :/

Comment: do you mean you want to binding an entry's text propetry(whicn user input a index),then another entry's text display the data witch the index ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT No, i'm adding dynamically entries but i want that every "text" entry property be binded to an element of a list depending on the index

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to bind an Element (index-based) from a C# Collection to an `Entry` you can do it this way.

Get your ViewModel instance and set it as the BindingContext on the Page

```
var viewModel = MainPageViewModel.GetInstace();
BindingContext = viewModel;
```

Create your entries in case you have more than one:

```
var textBox1 = new Entry()
{
    Placeholder = "ex Math homework",
    TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#18E1BF"),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};

var textBox2 = new Entry()
{
    Placeholder = "ex Science homework",
    TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#18E1BF"),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};

var textBox3 = new Entry()
{
    Placeholder = "ex English homework",
    TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#18E1BF"),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
```

Set your bindings. For this example, since I didn't get what `TaskNumber` meant I am using fixed indexes instead

```
textBox1.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "SubtasksList[0]");
textBox2.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "SubtasksList[1]");
textBox3.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "SubtasksList[2]");
```

Then you just add your Entries to your View. I am using a `StackLayout` which I called `ItemsContainer`

```
ItemsContainer.Children.Add(textBox1);
ItemsContainer.Children.Add(textBox2);
ItemsContainer.Children.Add(textBox3);
```

The above should give you a result like this:

[image]

A Xamarin Page with 3 programmatically created `Entries` each one bound to an item of a C# Collection.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

i write a simple sample,you could check it ,if it what you need ,here i add dynamically entries by a ListView:

the page axml:

```
<ContentPage>
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:GetListConverter x:Key="getList" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </ContentPage.Resources>

 <StackLayout Padding="10, 0">
    <Entry x:Name="entry1"
           Text=""
           Placeholder="enter search term"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry1},
                                Path=Text,
                                Converter={StaticResource getList}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding .}"></Entry>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
 </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

the **GetListConverter** (get the data list by the entry Text which user input the index):

```
public class GetListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            return null;
        }
        ObservableCollection<string> dataList = MainViewModel.GetInstance().SubtasksList[int.Parse((string)value) - 1];
        return dataList;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

the effec is like this:
[image]