# Binding to elements of a list in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, binding

So i've multiple Labels already created and i want to bind each label.text to an item of a list as the code shows. but it seems that i can't access the value of items by index

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,0,0,0" x:Name="stack0" IsVisible="True">
                        <Label  x:Name="CountRep0" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Counter[0]}"/>

                        <Label  x:Name="Objname0" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Objets_de_Commande[0]}"/>

                    </StackLayout>

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,0,0,0" x:Name="stack1" IsVisible="True">
                        <Label  x:Name="CountRep1" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Counter[1]}"/>

                        <Label  x:Name="Objname1" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Objets_de_Commande[1]}"/>

                    </StackLayout>
```

and I have 2 Lists "Objets_de_Commande" and "Counter"
do you have any ideas how i can make this work ?

Comment: I think you should use a ListView

Comment: what are they types of Objets_de_Commande and Counter?  Are they both public properties of your BindingContext?

Comment: @Jason Objets de commande is a string the other is int. and yes they are both public.

Comment: this is what i get : Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index a eu lieu

Comment: are you sure your two lists both have at least 2 elements in them?

Comment: @Jason yes, it seems that even simple binding does not work ! i tried binding the text of my labels to simple variables but i can't see nothing. Am I missing something ?

Comment: you can only bind to public properties

Comment: yes they are public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can binding an item of a list by the index . for example:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<string> Counter { get { return new List<string> { "1", "2" }; } }

    public List<string> Objets_de_Commande { get { return new List<string> { "test01", "test02" }; } }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,0,0,0" x:Name="stack0" IsVisible="True">
        <Label  x:Name="CountRep0" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Counter[0]}"/>
        <Label  x:Name="Objname0" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Objets_de_Commande[0]}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,0,0,0" x:Name="stack1" IsVisible="True">
        <Label  x:Name="CountRep1" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Counter[1]}"/>

        <Label  x:Name="Objname1" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Objets_de_Commande[1]}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Note:**

Just pay attention to the background and font color, if they are the same color,we could not see the result.
So I change the color of text to Black：

```
TextColor="Black"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible.

You can access a list item using an index-based Binding using the same code you are typed:

```
<Label  x:Name="Objname0" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Objets_de_Commande[0]}"/>
```

Just make sure you are setting the right `BindingContext` to the page in code behind.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58308456/1771254) other post shows how to do the binding in Code (`C#`) but it's not any different in XAML.

**Note:** As mentioned in one of the comments: it might be better for you to look into the `ListView` or the `CollectionView` instead.

Hope this helps.-